# Jest Unit Test for Nodejs/NestJS ExceptionFilter Catch Method

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

This is my BadRequestExceptionFilter written in Typescript for Nodejs/Nestjs

```
@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class BadRequestExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private logger: AppLoggerService) {}
  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();

    const status =
      exception instanceof BadRequestException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const message = {
      Title: exception.message.error,
      Type: 'Exception - BadRequestExceptionFilter',
      Detail: exception.message,
      Status: '',
    };

    this.logger.error(message, '');
    response.code(status).send({
      statusCode: status,
      ...(exception.getResponse() as object),
      timestamp: 'Exception - BadRequestException' + new Date().toISOString(),
    });
  }
}
```

This is my unit test andand 2 assert are done here. 
First assert is to check whether mockLogger.error called. It is working.
Second assert to check whether response.code(status).send() is called.
but getting this error.
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

```
const mockLogger = { error: jest.fn() };

const mockContext: any = {
  switchToHttp: () => ({
    getRequest: () => ({
      url: 'mock-url',
    }),
    getResponse: () => {
      const response = {
        code: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        send: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      };
      return response;
    },
  }),
};

describe('BadRequestExceptionFilter', () => {
  let filter: BadRequestExceptionFilter;

  beforeEach(() => {
    filter = new BadRequestExceptionFilter(mockLogger as any);
  });

  it('should catch and log the error', () => {
    const mockException: BadRequestException = new BadRequestException();

    mockException.name = 'BadRequestException';
    mockException.getResponse = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of('getResponse'));
    mockException.getStatus = () => 404;

    jest.fn(mockContext.switchToHttp().getResponse().send);
    filter.catch(mockException, mockContext);
    expect(mockLogger.error).toBeCalled();

    expect(
      mockContext
        .switchToHttp()
        .getResponse()
        .code().send,
    ).toBeCalled();
  });

});
```

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I am kind of stuck at this.

Comment: @tsadkanyitbarek check below my answer, I have achieved writing test cases successfully.

Answer (score 18):

I think its straight forward to write the test case for exception filter using Nest Testing module. Check below how I achieved the same:

```
// all-exception.filter.spec.ts
import {
    Test,
    TestingModule
} from '@nestjs/testing';
import {
    HttpStatus,
    HttpException
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './all-exceptions.filter';
import { AppLoggerService } from '../services/logger/app-logger.service';

const mockAppLoggerService = {
    info: jest.fn(),
    error: jest.fn(),
    warn: jest.fn(),
    debug: jest.fn()
};
const mockJson = jest.fn();
const mockStatus = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    json: mockJson
}));
const mockGetResponse = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    status: mockStatus
}));
const mockHttpArgumentsHost = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    getResponse: mockGetResponse,
    getRequest: jest.fn()
}));

const mockArgumentsHost = {
    switchToHttp: mockHttpArgumentsHost,
    getArgByIndex: jest.fn(),
    getArgs: jest.fn(),
    getType: jest.fn(),
    switchToRpc: jest.fn(),
    switchToWs: jest.fn()
};

describe('System header validation service', () => {
    let service: AllExceptionsFilter;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                AllExceptionsFilter,
                {
                    provide: AppLoggerService,
                    useValue: mockAppLoggerService
                },
            ]
        }).compile();
        service = module.get<AllExceptionsFilter>(AllExceptionsFilter);
    });

    describe('All exception filter tests', () => {

        it('should be defined', () => {
            expect(service).toBeDefined();
        });

        it('Http exception', () => {
            service.catch(
                new HttpException('Http exception', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),
                mockArgumentsHost
            );
            expect(mockHttpArgumentsHost).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockHttpArgumentsHost).toBeCalledWith();
            expect(mockGetResponse).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockGetResponse).toBeCalledWith();
            expect(mockStatus).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockStatus).toBeCalledWith(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            expect(mockJson).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockJson).toBeCalledWith({
                message: 'Http exception'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a ctx.getRequest() is not a function when I try to run this test. Any idea why? @iAviator

Comment: I have edited the above code mock getRequest fn added. You can replace jest.fn() with your custom mock

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this and it worked!

```
export const contextMock = (roles?: string[]) => {
    const ctx: any = {}
    ctx.switchToHttp = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        getRequest: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(requestMock()),
        getResponse: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(responseMock()),
    })
    ctx.getHandler = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ roles }) as Function

    return ctx
}

-----------------------------------------------

const ctxMock = contextMock() as any

expect(ctxMock.switchToHttp).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(ctxMock.switchToHttp().getResponse).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(ctxMock.switchToHttp().getResponse().status).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(ctxMock.switchToHttp().getResponse().json).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

As I understood , we always have to pass a mock for the "expect".

Answer (score 2):

In your filter, you have `...(expection.getResponse() as object)`, but `exception` doesn't have the function `getResponse()` on it. Instead you would need to switch to the http context first

Answer (score 1):

I modified mine a bit to make the message work. I was getting `undefined` message and my tests wasn't passing. So I had to modify it as follows:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HttpStatus, HttpException, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GlobalExceptionsFilter } from './http-filter.exception';

const mockAppLoggerService = {
  info: jest.fn(),
  error: jest.fn(),
  warn: jest.fn(),
  debug: jest.fn(),
};
const mockJson = jest.fn();
const mockStatus = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  json: mockJson,
}));
const mockGetResponse = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  status: mockStatus,
}));
const mockHttpArgumentsHost = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  getResponse: mockGetResponse,
  getRequest: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockArgumentsHost = {
  switchToHttp: mockHttpArgumentsHost,
  getArgByIndex: jest.fn(),
  getArgs: jest.fn(),
  getType: jest.fn(),
  switchToRpc: jest.fn(),
  switchToWs: jest.fn(),
};

describe('System header validation service', () => {
  let service: GlobalExceptionsFilter;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        GlobalExceptionsFilter,
        {
          provide: Logger,
          useValue: mockAppLoggerService,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get<GlobalExceptionsFilter>(GlobalExceptionsFilter);
  });

  describe('All exception filter tests', () => {
    it('should be defined', () => {
      expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('Http exception', () => {
      service.catch(
        new HttpException({ message: 'Sample Exception' }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),
        mockArgumentsHost
      );
      expect(mockHttpArgumentsHost).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockHttpArgumentsHost).toBeCalledWith();
      expect(mockGetResponse).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockGetResponse).toBeCalledWith();
      expect(mockStatus).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockStatus).toBeCalledWith(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      expect(mockJson).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockJson).toBeCalledWith({
        message: 'Sample Exception',
        status: false,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

My test eventually passed

```
 PASS  src/utils/exceptions/http-filter.exception.spec.ts
  System header validation service
    All exception filter tests
      ✓ should be defined (6 ms)
      ✓ Http exception (5 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.225 s, estimated 2 s
```